# How to clear focus from an inputfield in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an inputfield and I want to get rid of the focus on it, after i click the submit button.

Any suggestions on how I would go about this?

Answer (score 21):

You can add ref to your text input: `<TextInput ref="input">` and then call `this.refs.input.blur()`.

Comment: I like the idea, but that does only work if you have some kind of input or if you have isFocused() method... e.g. I have a TextInput for a search field with a listview under it. If you search something and scroll the result in the listview you can't toggle the keyboard to go away

Answer (score 10):

```
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Keyboard.dismiss() will remove focus from all text input fields in view and hide keyboard. 
and for specific field you can use the above mentioned method

```
<TextInput ref="input">

this.refs.input.blur()
```

Comment: I like how this guy just combines the answers people gave years ago and makes it a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

It may not seem like the obvious answer, but you can try the static method Keyboard.dismiss() for this.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard
I needed to remove the focus when uncertain which input might have it.  This did the trick.

Answer (score -3):

In my use case I explicitly needed the input to lose focus (and require the user to touch it again with the intent to edit).

The kludge in [this blog post](http://heha-key.blogspot.com/2015/07/react-native-remove-focus-on-textinput.html) was what worked for me the best:

```js
this.refs.input.setNativeProps({'editable':false});
this.refs.input.setNativeProps({'editable':true});
```